# Why Dr Watson did not capture/generate dump when my application crashed?

Tags: c++, crash, desktop

I've already set drwtsn32 to full dump and logging but it does not generate a dmp and drwtsn32.log after my app (built with c++) crashed.

Are there crashes that cannot be captured by drwtsn32? If yes, how are you supposed to investigate this crash?

Thanks!

Comment: "Crash" is not a technical term. It's OK when users report it, but we need a better description here. If your app calls `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)`, it's not something that drwtsn32 would consider an unexpected process termination

Comment: See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chaun/2013/11/12/steps-to-catch-a-simple-crash-dump-of-a-crashing-process/ and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787181.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396. By some types of security critical errors Windows just terminates the process without warning and possibility to handle it.